# How can implement deep linking in new facebook sdk in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, deep-linking

How can I implement deep linking in new Facebook SDK in ios?

Answer (score 1):

To deep link on Facebook, you'll need to use their *App Links* metatags on your website. The most confusing thing about Facebook’s App Links is that they are not actually links, they are metatags that go on your website. For example, here's how IMDB would add App Links to their movie site for The Rock:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
...
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="342792525" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="imdb://title/tt0117500" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="IMDb Movies & TV" />

<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.imdb.mobile" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="imdb://title/tt0117500" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="IMDb Movies & TV" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

You can see that their deep linking URI and path are `imdb://title/tt0117500` and they have to specify it on their site so that the Facebook robot can scrape it.

Once the metatags are on the site, when the link is posted to Facebook's feed, they will open the app directly if it's installed by calling the URI specified in the metatags. Then, in your app's App Delegate, you can receive the URI specified in the `openUrl` method like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"opened app from URL %@", [url description]);
    return YES;
}
```

You can parse the URL in that method and open the View Controller that will display the appropriate data associated with the URL.

Comment: In addition to this great answer; you can read more on this here: https://developers.facebook.com/products/app-links

Comment: i already do this functionality and my app link is work properly. but i can not get data post on facebook.i want below functionality------- any user click any post on facebook then take this post data and open ios app.if app is installed.

Comment: Alpesh - Facebook doesn't seem to acknowledge App Links on iOS. I work  at Branch (https://branch.io) to help devs do just that, and we still have to rely on Javascript tricks to open up the app on iOS. Android works great though.